# vscode keep selecting wrong python version for venv

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-venv

What I am doing is to run this project

```
https://github.com/CorentinJ/Real-Time-Voice-Cloning
```

It requires 3.7 and all library versions depends on that.
BUG:When I try to install requirements.txt it gives me error

```
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [264 lines of output]
      setup.py:66: RuntimeWarning: NumPy 1.20.3 may not yet support Python 3.10.
```

I have installed both Python 3.10 and python 3.7 on my Windows machine.
In `vscode` even after I manually select python 3.7 as my interpreter, and after I set a PATH system environment that points to python 3.7 folder and push it to top of the list, and after I rename my Python.exe of version 3.7 to Python3.7.exe, when I type `pip install -r requirements.txt`

It still  gives that error suggesting that I am using Python 3.10

`Vscode` is refuse to use the correct version.

What I am missing?

Comment: The question title says "venv" and the tags say "python-venv", but the question doesn't say anything about virtual environments.

Comment: Did you use other extensions to run your scripts? For example, Code Runner.

Answer (score 0):

After you change your python interpreter, your terminal may still be using the previous python 3.10.

You can try to kill the current terminal and run your python file by clicking **Run Python File** button or debug the script by shortcuts **F5**:

[image]

VSCode will automatically activate the selected venv Python environment for you and run the files in the new environment.

You can read [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_working-with-python-interpreters) for more details about Python interpreter. Hope this can help.